# How to connect Alloy model with JAVA or Python?

Tags: java, python, alloy

Can somebody help me and may be give some explanation or examples with my problem? Assuming that there are no "**numbers**" or "**integers**" (Alloy works with **entities**), how can I use my model (which I created in Alloy) through JAVA or Python? 
How to "connect" Alloy's model with other languages?

Thanks! 
Vadik.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass this model to Python, you would need to create new data types. This can be done with classes.

For example:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

stephen = Person('Stephen', 27)
```

There you have a new data type: Person

You would need to create the right classes to represent the same types of your Alloy model.

Comment: Thank you Agustin! To be honest I mean something different. Suppose I have Alloy model. Alloy Analyzer finds counterexample to my assertions or give me some instances to my predicates. How can I use Alloy model and the results of Analyzer through JAVA or Python?

Comment: "How can I use Alloy model and the results of Analyzer through JAVA or Python?" to do what?
Sorry for the misunderstanding @Lukmanov. You'll need to show us an example of what you mean, I'm not have knowledge about Alloy. 
If you want to use the data in both cases you will need to create a parser for extract data of the two types of files, the Alloy model file and the output file. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example: http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/code/EvaluatorExample.java.html.

You have to use Alloy (jar file) as a library in your Java application.